# My github page is connected to my domain but there is no website which reflects my code. What to do?

Tags: github

I have filled custom domain field with my domain and took 4 ip adresses to my domain acount website. After that, my github page redirects to the domain I wanted but there is no my website, it displays the website of domain owner company. what should i do?

Comment: so you enabled github pages for a given repo (and it works), then you wanted to serve them from a custom domain. At that point please explain what you did onwards. I've never had to enter IPs, I just CNAME whatever github gave me like "page.user.com" => "<user or organization>.github.io"

Comment: hello, thanks for responding. I went to github custom domain insturction page and took 4 ip adresses and put them into domain website ns fields.

Comment: and then i go to my github page link it redirects to my domain but content is not mine

Answer (score 0):

This link explains [how to use a custom domain on Github pages.](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site)

You need to make sure you put the 4 IP addresses you mentioned in the A host record area of the DNS for the domain.

Also, you will need to add a record in the "www" CNAME host record which points to yourusername.github.io for this to work.